# why the year generated by newcommand doesn't work as number in latex

Tags: date

I have create the following code in latex and when I am using \Year in the formatdate function it complain and I don't understand why

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{datetime,calculator}

\ADD{\the\year}{1}{\ans}
\newcommand{\Year}{\ifthenelse{\month = 12}
                              {\ifthenelse{\the\day<20}{\the\year}{\ans}}
                              {\the\year}
                  }
\newcommand{\tDate}{\formatdate{03}{02}{\Year}}
\begin{document}

\Year

The date is \tDate
\end{document}
```

Error 
Missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: Try https://pastebin.com/N8R61624

Comment: package datetime is obsolete according to CTAN
They suggest using datetime2
this one seems compatible with ifthenelse
On page 61 on today's manual of datetime2
http://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf
there is an example of how to display the date in English.

Comment: Crap, it does not work with datetime2 either...

Comment: Could you explain a little about the calculation you want to achieve? "If the month in the year is 12 and the day is less than 20, then the year remains the same, otherwise it's the following year..." What's the logic here?